# fflush doesn't work in named pipe

Tags: c

I have this code:
The program got stuck when the first child sending to the second child the data, 
the second child do fscanf and then stuck because he cant read i cant find the reason for it.
please help me to find out how can i make sure that the fflush will transfer the data.

```
int main()
{
    pid_t childPid ; //Child's and father process id.
    int i ; //An index to create children in loop.
    unsigned int st_search_prime = 0 ;

    if((mkfifo(FIRST_FIFO, S_IFIFO | 0644) == FAIL && errno != EEXIST) ||
       (mkfifo(SECOND_FIFO, S_IFIFO | 0644) == FAIL && errno != EEXIST))
    {
        perror("Cannot create fifo file") ;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    }
    //create the children
    for(i = 0 ; i < NUM_OF_CHILDS  ; i++)
    {
        childPid = fork() ;
        if(childPid < 0)    //Fork failed.
        {
            perror("Cannot fork()") ;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
        }
        else if(childPid == CHILD)  //child process
        {
            if(i == FIRST_SON)  //the 1st child process
                doChild1(st_search_prime) ;
            else        //the 2nd child process.
                doChild2(st_search_prime) ;
        }
    }
    //wait for the children to exit.
    for(i = 0 ; i < NUM_OF_CHILDS ; i++)
        wait(&childPid) ;

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS) ;
}

void doChild1(unsigned int st_search_prime)
{
    int counter = 0 ; //Counter for N successfully raffle .
    FILE* fdw1 ;
    FILE* fdr2 ;

    if((!(fdw1 = fopen(FIRST_FIFO, "w"))))
    {
        perror("Cannot open fifo file for w/r") ;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    }

    if((!(fdr2 = fopen(SECOND_FIFO, "r"))))
    {
        perror("Cannot open fifo file for w/r") ;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    }

    for(; counter < N ; counter++)
    {
        st_search_prime = raffle_prime(st_search_prime) ;
        **fprintf(fdw1, "%u\n", st_search_prime) ;
        fflush(fdw1) ;**
        printf("%u\n", st_search_prime) ;
        fscanf(fdr2, "%u\n", &st_search_prime) ;
    }
    fclose(fdw1) ;
    fclose(fdr2) ;

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) ;
}

void doChild2(unsigned int st_search_prime)
{
    int counter = 0 ; //Counter for N successfully raffle .
    FILE* fdw2 ;
    FILE* fdr1 ;

    if((!(fdr1 = fopen(FIRST_FIFO, "r"))))
    {
        perror("Cannot open fifo file for w/r") ;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    }
    if(!(fdw2 = fopen(SECOND_FIFO, "w")))
    {
        perror("Cannot open fifo file for w/r") ;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    }

    for(; counter < N ; counter++)
    {
        **fscanf(fdr1, "%u\n", &st_search_prime);**
        st_search_prime = raffle_prime(st_search_prime) ;
        fprintf(fdw2, "%u\n", st_search_prime) ;
        fflush(fdw2) ;
        printf("%u\n", st_search_prime) ;
    }
    fclose(fdr1) ;
    fclose(fdw2) ;

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) ;
}
```

Comment: Consider calling read() for a fixed number of bytes, then call sscanf on the string returned by read.  read on a pipe will also return fewer bytes - fscanf is blocking because the file pointer is not where you assume it to be.  read() doesn't "care" and will just return what is there.

Comment: As it is, your issue may be related to pieces of your code that are missing. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding call `setlinebuf(fdw1)` - this should help.

This call forces flushing buffer after newline. Also you can use `setvbuf()` with parameter `_IOLBF` to get the same effect or with `_IONBF` to disable buffering completely.

Comment: tnx, but still the program stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I believe is the use of `\n` in your `fscanf` pattern.  The manual page for `fscanf` says:

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives  which 
>   describe how  to  process  the sequence of input characters.  If
>   processing of a directive fails, no further input is  read,  and 
>   scanf()  returns.   A "failure"  can  be either of the following:
>   input failure, meaning that input characters were unavailable, or
>   matching  failure,  meaning  that the input was inappropriate ...

Also, under directives we have:

> A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see
>   isspace(3)).  This directive matches  any  amount  of  white space,
>   including none, in the input.

So, when in `doChild2` you use the `fscanf` pattern `"%u\n"` the pattern is made of two input directives, the `%u` which matches the incoming number, then `\n` which matches the incoming newline (white space).  At this point the `fscanf` will continue looking for more input, which as no more input is sent results in your program blocking.

And why does `fscanf` go back to look for more input? The first quote above tells us the two conditions for termination, either no more input; well the fifo is still open, so we don't know that more input is not on the way, so that condition is not met, alternatively, `fscanf` will return if a directive fails to match; but that has not happened yet.

As far as a fix goes then removing the `\n` from the `fscanf` pattern should be enough.  The manual page tells us that:

> Most conversions discard initial white space characters...

and this is the case for `%u`, so if you send using a pattern of `%u\n` but `fscanf` with a pattern of `%u` then the `\n` will serve to cause a match failure on the `%u` directive, causing `fscanf` to return.  This will leave the `\n` in the input buffer, however, the next call to `fscanf` will discard the initial white space (newline) and all should be well.